# What is the difference between `defaults -currentHost read -globalDomain` and `defaults -host hrk read -globalDomain`?

Tags: defaults

My username is `hrk` and I am currently logged in as `hrk` on the hostname of `Hrishikeshs-MacBook-Pro`.
Why is the output of the following 2 commands different?
Shouldn't the output be the same?
Where can I find the official explanation besides the `man defaults` page?

`defaults -host Hrishikeshs-MacBook-Pro read -globalDomain`

```plist
{
    AKLastEmailListRequestDateKey = "2022-10-26 21:50:38 +0000";
    AKLastIDMSEnvironment = 0;
    AppleAntiAliasingThreshold = 4;
    AppleInterfaceStyle = Dark;
    AppleLanguages =     (
        "en-IN"
    );
    AppleLanguagesDidMigrate = "12.6";
    AppleLanguagesSchemaVersion = 2000;
    AppleLocale = "en_IN";
    AppleMeasurementUnits = Centimeters;
    AppleMetricUnits = 1;
    AppleMiniaturizeOnDoubleClick = 0;
    AppleShowAllExtensions = 1;
    AppleTemperatureUnit = Celsius;
    NSAutomaticCapitalizationEnabled = 1;
    NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled = 1;
    NSAutomaticPeriodSubstitutionEnabled = 1;
    NSAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled = 1;
    NSAutomaticSpellingCorrectionEnabled = 1;
    NSAutomaticTextCompletionEnabled = 1;
    NSLinguisticDataAssetsRequestLastInterval = 86400;
    NSLinguisticDataAssetsRequestTime = "2022-10-26 14:45:16 +0000";
    NSLinguisticDataAssetsRequested =     (
        en
    );
    NSLinguisticDataAssetsRequestedByChecker =     (
        en
    );
    NSPreferredWebServices =     {
        NSWebServicesProviderWebSearch =         {
            NSDefaultDisplayName = Google;
            NSProviderIdentifier = "com.google.www";
        };
    };
    NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems =     (
                {
            on = 1;
            replace = omw;
            with = "On my way!";
        }
    );
    WebAutomaticSpellingCorrectionEnabled = 1;
    "com.apple.finder.SyncExtensions" =     {
        collaborationMap =         {
        };
        dirMap =         {
        };
    };
    "com.apple.sound.beep.flash" = 0;
    "com.apple.springing.delay" = "0.5";
    "com.apple.springing.enabled" = 1;
    "com.apple.trackpad.forceClick" = 1;
    "com.apple.trackpad.scaling" = 1;
    userMenuExtraStyle = 2;
}
```

`defaults -currentHost read -globalDomain`

```plist
{
    "com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior" = 1;
    "com.apple.trackpad.enableSecondaryClick" = 1;
    "com.apple.trackpad.fiveFingerPinchSwipeGesture" = 2;
    "com.apple.trackpad.fourFingerHorizSwipeGesture" = 2;
    "com.apple.trackpad.fourFingerPinchSwipeGesture" = 2;
    "com.apple.trackpad.fourFingerVertSwipeGesture" = 2;
    "com.apple.trackpad.momentumScroll" = 1;
    "com.apple.trackpad.pinchGesture" = 1;
    "com.apple.trackpad.rotateGesture" = 1;
    "com.apple.trackpad.scrollBehavior" = 2;
    "com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerDragGesture" = 0;
    "com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerHorizSwipeGesture" = 2;
    "com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerTapGesture" = 0;
    "com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerVertSwipeGesture" = 2;
    "com.apple.trackpad.twoFingerDoubleTapGesture" = 1;
    "com.apple.trackpad.twoFingerFromRightEdgeSwipeGesture" = 3;
    "com.apple.trackpad.version" = 5;
}
```

PS -
Not a duplicate of - [What is 'currentHost' for, in defaults?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/353528/what-is-currenthost-for-in-defaults)

Answer (score 1):

## `defaults` Manual

According to the [`defaults` manual page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/defaults/), the `host` and `currentHost` flags limit the scope of the information shown:

> **-currentHost** : Restricts preferences operations to the host the user is currently logged in on.
>
> **-host** *hostname* : Restricts preferences operations to hostname.

Use the command `man defaults` to see this documentation.

### CoreFoundation

This tool and the flags functionality are ultimately built upon macOS's [CoreFoundation Preferences Utilities](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/preferences_utilities?language=objc):

> Core Foundation provides a simple, standard way to manage user (and application) preferences. Core Foundation stores preferences as key-value pairs that are assigned a scope using a combination of user name, application ID, and host (computer) names. This makes it possible to save and retrieve preferences that apply to different classes of users. Core Foundation preferences is useful to all applications that support user preferences.

Comment: I have updated my question. I had already gone through the manual page just forgot to mention it.

Comment: The `defaults` manual page is the only "official explanation", with the underlying CoreFoundation implementation being the original reference implementation.

Comment: Okay, but the main question remains unanswered as to why the difference in the two command's output.